# Backfill values by distributing values across prior NaNs in a timeseries with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, interpolation

I have a time series where each observation represents the total amount of something since the last observation, if there is no observation in that timestep then the value is reported as NaN. An example of the format:

```
Timestep  Value
1          10
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          9
5          NaN
6          NaN
7          NaN
8          16
9          NaN
10         NaN
```

What I would like to do is distribute the observed values across the NaNs prior to it. For example, a sequence like [5, NaN, NaN, 6] would become [5, 2, 2, 2] with the final observation, 6, distributed over the last 2 NaN values. Applied to the dataframe above the desired output would be:

```
Timestep  Value
1          10
2          3
3          3
4          3
5          4
6          4
7          4
8          4
9          NaN
10         NaN
```

I've tried doing this with some of the pandas backfill and interpolate methods but haven't found anything which quite does what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `transform`

```
df.Value.bfill().div(
    df.groupby(df.Value.notna()[::-1].cumsum()).Value.transform('size')
)

0    10.0
1     3.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     4.0
6     4.0
7     4.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

### `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`

```
a = df.Value.notna().values
f, u = pd.factorize(a[::-1].cumsum()[::-1])

df.Value.bfill().div(np.bincount(f)[f])

0    10.0
1     3.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     4.0
6     4.0
7     4.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Alternative shorter version.  This works because `cumsum` naturally gives me what `factorize` does.

```
a = df.Value.notna().values[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
df.Value.bfill().div(np.bincount(a)[a])
```

---

### Details

In both options above, we need to identify where the null values are and use `cumsum` on the reversed series to define groups.  In the `transform` option, I use `groupby` and `size` to count the size of those groups.

The second option uses bin counting and slicing to get at the same series.

Thank you @ScottBoston for reminding me to mention the reversed element `[::-1]`

Comment: I learned the [::-1] trick a long time ago from one of your post.  I think that is key to this solution. And particularly, when thinking about problems that affect "prior" values in a series.

Answer (score 4):

Count the *cumulative* NA, then we do `update`

```
s=df.Value.notnull().cumsum().shift(1)
df.Value.update(df.Value.bfill()/s.groupby(s).transform('count'))
df
Out[885]: 
   Timestep  Value
0         1   10.0
1         2    3.0
2         3    3.0
3         4    3.0
4         5    4.0
5         6    4.0
6         7    4.0
7         8    4.0
8         9    NaN
9        10    NaN
```

Comment: Nice method also.  I like the shift. +1